# Plotly: Map is not being displayed, no error raised either

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am trying to plot a USA map using plotly package. Code is getting executed but nothing is getting displayed on the screen.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

data = dict(type = 'choropleth',locations = ['AZ','CA','NY'],locationmode='USA-states',colorscale='Portland',text=['text1','text2','text3']
            ,z=[1,0,2.0,3.0],colorbar={'title' : 'USA States Data'})
layout = dict(geo={'scope' : 'usa'})
fig = go.Figure(data=[data],layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Why nothing is getting displayed and no error is also raised?

Answer (score 0):

Ran your code, it's working fine for me.

[image]

(Also, try and make your title more descriptive of the problem so that if someone faces a similar problem, they can easily find your question.)